# How access files from macOS that are stored locally in the Files App on a iPadOS or iOS device

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, ios, ipados

How can i access files from macOS (v10.14, v10.15.beta) that are stored locally on a iOS or iPadOS device via the File app and that are not uploaded to iCloud or other Cloud services and are not stored in a folder from Apps like Pages, Keynote? Obviously not even synchronization does copy those files. I'm using iPadOS (v13.1). Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible on iPadOS. You can request that it be added as a feature by going to www.apple.com/feedback

Comment: Not in files app, but airdrop works in such situations.